# Existence of solution to maximization problem

Tags: optimization

I'm a first year Finance grad student and we're learning utility maximization problem now. We have been assuming that a solution to these problems exists.  Are there any general theorem about the existence of maximization solution on $\mathbb{R}^n$? I have encountered once that "A utility maximization problem with a continuous utility function on a compact set has solution". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are general theorems about existence and uniqueness. The one you cited is Weierstrass' [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) (notice budget sets are compact only if no price is zero). See Mas Colell's Microeconomic Theory or Varian's Microeconomic Analysis or any graduate level book on microeconomics for references.